# Some questions about WPMU

Tags: multisite

I just activated wordpress multisite in my site.

I have few questions.

1) WPMU and wordpress multisite both are same?

2) I created a network in my site. I created like site1.mydomain.com, site2.mydomain.com etc.
   Is it possible to make my subdomains posts summary appear in my main domain?

3) Is it possible to make users access all subdomains with single registration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) WordPress MultiUser (WPMU) was the term used before WP3. WPMS is for version 3 and newer.

2) Subsite posts appearing on the main site is built into BuddyPress. You will need to install BP to your multisite setup for this to work.

3) There are several plugins that achieve this either through a) a single user database shared across all sites, or b) duplication of users with differing user permissions per site.

Answer (score 0):

2) There are several options to choose from to show posts from a subdomain on your main site. You may use rss feeds, a plugin such as bbAggregate (disclaimer: I'm the plugin author) or BuddyPress as suggested by Bitmap Media, although just using BuddyPress for this rather small options seems like overkill to me. It all depends on what you would like to achieve. What would like to achieve?

3) The answer given by Bitmap Media is incomplete. WordPress Multisite allows you to login once to access all your sites. As long as you user has been granted access to this site.